# How exactly does //= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my application.scss, but I don't understand how it works:

```
//= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
```

What I do know:

- Without it, the application doesn't get the boostrap styling added to the .css file.
- I know `require` includes the css file that goes by the name of the argument in application's css.
- I know it's conventional for these 'require' calls to be commented out, but I have no idea why, it's not a convention I've not seen anywhere else.
- I've searched my entire application for directories similar to `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap` to figure out where the bootstrap css is coming from. But a search of the entire app doesn't reveal such directories (nor any files called bootstrap.css or bootstrap.scss).
- The app I'm working on uses sprockets and webpacker. I *think* this syntax is unique to sprockets, although I'm not sure.

So **TL;DR** I understand what this line does, but could someone explain how `//= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap` is working to get that css into the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sprockets directive

Sprockets is a gem for assets compiling

So there are [few directives](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives) with such syntax

> `//= require` - Add the contents of a file to current
>
> `//= require_self` - Change order of where current contents are concatenated to current
>
> `//= require_directory` - Add contents of each file in a folder to current
>
> `//= require_tree` - Add contents of all files in all directories in a path to current
>
> `//= link` - Make target file compile and be publicly available without adding contents to current
>
> `//= link_directory` - Make target directory compile and be publicly available without adding contents to current
>
> `//= link_tree` - Make target tree compile and be publicly available without adding contents to current
>
> `//= depend_on` - Recompile current file if target has changed
>
> `//= stub` - Ignore target file

These directives are parsed with [`Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/c84ddbf3fa3ddfe4388a4dc307e6fb38cdb25d23/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb) entity

And about how it works with other libraries

There is `config.assets.paths` in the app when you use sprockets. So sprockets search assets there. For example in `node_modules` folder. It looks that you install bootstrap using yarn and this style sheets are in that directory

But if you install with gem, [this gem add](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/804e3dd5a00f2994409b1bf845f1fa5f073210ec/lib/bootstrap/engine.rb) to `config.assets.paths` its own paths

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @mechincov's answer. I still couldn't work out where this bootstrap file was actually coming from (since there was no bootstrap directory in my app, and definitely no file located at `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` - none that I could find, anyway.

But I (sort of) figured out where it was coming from. I believe it's coming into the app via yarn.lock, which contains this:

```
bootstrap@^4.5.2:
  version "4.6.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.6.1.tgz#bc25380c2c14192374e8dec07cf01b2742d222a2"
  integrity sha512-0dj+VgI9Ecom+rvvpNZ4MUZJz8dcX7WCX+eTID9+/8HgOkv3dsRzi8BGeZJCQU6flWQVYxwTQnEZFrmJSEO7og==
```

package.json also contains a reference to bootstrap (and associated libraries jQuery and popper), so perhaps that's where it originates:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
```

Comment: It is from `node_modules` folder as I wrote :)

Comment: @mechnicov thanks for letting me know (I read your answer immediately, but didn't realise more had been included soon after). Thanks for the great info